# How to reference Google Map tag in a JS file

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on ASP.Net MVC and we're using an external .JS file to place all javascript code.
I firstly placed the below Google Map code in the View and it is working nice displaying the map in the view page... but when I sent my code for code-review, code-review folks require me to reference it in the .JS file.  I tried so many times to put it in a .JS file but I can't have it displayed in a view.

Seems like they want the google map initialization variable and the google map js script inside the js file **airplanDetail.js** and, only have the reference in the view page. They want clean code/view page

Can you please assist?

```
                            <div class="googleMapAPI">
                            @{
                                var googleAPIKey = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CWU_GoogleAPI_Key"];
                                <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=@googleAPIKey&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
                            }
```

So in the ASP.Net MVC view page, at the bottom, there's a the below code that refence to the JS file.

```
@section Scripts {    
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Views/Product/airplanDetail.js")
}
```

and inside the **airplanDetails.js** file there's a code looks like the below

```
$(function () {    

    Initialize();        
});

function Initialize() {

google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

var propertyLatitude = document.getElementById("latitudId").value;
var propertyLongitude = document.getElementById("longitudId").value;
var propertyLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(propertyLatitude, propertyLongitude);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: propertyLocation,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.G_NORMAL_MAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(propertyLatitude, propertyLongitude);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Location found'
});


marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png')

}
```

Comment: Why no one wants to reply? 17 views but 0 folks want to help. please sir/madam I really need help. I'm stuck for the whole day.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the script tag in the  section, ie:

```
<html>
<head>
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Views/Product/airplanDetail.js")
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```